# How do I set the $.Scroll for iOS and Tablets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cross-browser, tablet

I'm trying to set the scroll with jQuery / JavaScript. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the viewport for iOS and tablet PC's. Any help will be appreciated. I need to use the $.Scroll for design / Animation purposes.

Thanks,

Here's what I have so far:

```
  

    var isIphone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;
    var isIpod = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null;
    var isIpad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

    // now set one variable for all iOS devices
    // What do I do for Tablet PC's?

    var isIos = isIphone || isIpod || isIpad;

    jQuery(function ($) {
      $.Window = $(window); // We'll use this later on 
      $.Body = $('body');
      if ( !isIos ) {
        // Ternary for desktop
        $.Scroll = ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.msie) ? $('html') : $.Body;
      } else {
        // Need to detect iOS and Tablet PC's
        $.Scroll = $.Body;
      }
    });
```

UPDATE:

Thanks, for the input so far!

I've figured out how to access the iOS touch event:

```
  

    $.Window
      .bind('touchmove',
        function (e) {
          //code goes here
      })
      .bind('scroll',
        function (e) {
          //code goes here
      })
```

This seems to work on both scroll and touch events.

Comment: Do you mean to use "scrollTop(value)" (http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)? What is "$.Scroll"? A plugin? It looks like you are setting the element that does the scrolling; I've not seen anything like that.

Comment: I'm creating an object called $.Scroll to help define the location of scrollTop. I think the problem is that iOS doesn't seem to recognize $('html') or $('body') as the object of scrollTop, which results in no animation if scrollTop is used as the .animate property.

Comment: I tried using the $.Body object an it works, but is really choppy. I heard that jQuery scrollTop() is buggy on iOS, is this correct?

Comment: What I really want to do is use the touch scroll event, but I'm having trouble finding what this object is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS stops timers on scroll, so for the most part timer based animations are not going to work. My scrolling was good to go, it's just that jQuery .animate does not work well with iOS Safari's implementation of the scroll type.

Answer (score 0):

I think window.scrollTo(x, y) will get what you want, but you need to ensure the window is actually scrollable (i.e. the contents are larger than the window and body overflow is scrollable).

**Sidenote**: I've not seen anyone store variables *in* the jQuery library like that. Why not just do `var scrollableObject = ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.msie) ? $('html') : $.Body;`?